# Unable to delete applications from Bluemix dashboard

Tags: ibm-cloud, alchemyapi

I created one application using alchemy-api services. I am unable to delete it from dashboard now. Not sure what's the reason . Please suggest.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you asking how to delete an application off your dashboard? Or do you know how and there is an error you ran into? if the later can you please provide the error?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Its deleted now. The Bluemix session needs to be refreshed after deleting any app or service.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to delete a Bluemix app is to use the menu in the upper right corner of the application tile on the dashboard. This deletes the app but may not always remove the tile itself. To remove the tile, simply refresh your dashboard.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response. Yes , that's correct. When I open Bluemix in a new session , it didn't show deleted app and service.